# Spotify Web API - Session Class not found (Composer)

Tags: php, api, composer-php, spotify

I'm new to composer and I tried to install the https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php Package.
So I followed the instruction from the Readme File. Regarding Composer the installation was completed.

My webpage always returns an 500 error and my error.log says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SpotifyWebAPI\\Session' not found in /mnt/web419/b0/52/5337952/htdocs/websitecom/www/jukebox/index.php:4
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
<?

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session(
'XXX',
'XXX',
'http://example.com'
);

$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
$api->setAccessToken($session->getAccessToken());

print_r($api->me());
} else {
$options = [
'scope' => [
'user-read-email',
],
];

header('Location: ' . $session->getAuthorizeUrl($options));
die();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try the full php tag: `<?php`. The 505 error is very bizarre, as it means "HTTP Version Not Supported"

Comment: Sorry, my bad "Error 500" not "505"

Comment: @AppleWeb Did you find a fix for this?